# Select count query to a previous select query in mysql

Tags: mysql

How do I send a select count query to a select query?

This is the query I send first:

```
SELECT test_id, sum(is_test) as totaltest FROM `tests` group by test_id
```

I want to know the total amount of items, so I guess I need to do a select count to this query. Right?

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible that you want the `found_rows()` function.

You can call this after your query to get the number of rows returned:

```
select found_rows()
```

You can read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Answer (score 0):

do

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (your_query)
```